# How to set allowed characters in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to set allowed characters for my forms. How can I do this limitation in Django 1.11?

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Customer

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
        'order_id','full_name','company','email',
        'phone_number','note')
```

To be more specific in 'full_name' , 'company' and 'note' fields I just want to allow digits and letters. In 'email' field want to allow digits , letters, "-" , "_" , "." and "@" characters. And in 'phone_number' field want to digits and "+" , "#" , "()" characters.

Comment: Can you give examples of what characters you would allow/disallow including which fields?

Comment: In 'full_name' , 'company' and 'note' fields I just want to allow digits and letters. In 'email' field want to allow digits , letters, "-" , "_" , "." and "@" characters. And in 'phone_number' field want to digits and "+" , "#" , "()" characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegexValidator for example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.RegexValidator

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

AlphanumericValidator = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[AlphanumericValidator])
```

But then you need to handle an error when someone provide character that is not allowed